# sed to read one file and delete pattern in second file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a list of users that have logged in during the past 180 days and a list of  total users from LDAP. Each list is within text file and each name is on its own line. With sed or awk can I have a script read from current-users.txt and delete from total-users.txt to give me a text document that has all of the inactive accounts for the past 180 days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to sed or awk, `grep` suffices:

```
grep -vf current-users.txt total-users
```

It returns all the lines that are in `total_users` but not in `current-users.txt`.

- `grep -f` gets parameters from a file.
- `grep -v` inverts the result.

#### Example

```
$ cat total_users 
one
two
three
four

$ cat some_users 
two
four

$ grep -vf some_users total_users 
one
three
```

Comment: Awesome, much easier. Thanks!

Comment: Good to read that. Wasn't it exactly what you needed? You can consider adding `-w` to grep to match full words, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' current_users total_users
```

Comment: Actually this is more accurate.